# jquery hover on and off issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using jQuery to hide and show a div on hover of its parent div. It works but the only issue is that when you hover over and off a few times really quick it preforms each fade in and out over and over again untill its completed it as many times as you moved the mouse on and off.
see : http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerIn-handlerOut
the first example's demo here if your hover over them all a few times really quick then watch you can see what I mean.

here is my code, Is ther any way to make it more user friendly and not repeat it self so many times?

```
    $(function () { 
        $('.hide').fadeOut("fast"); 

        $( ".fourth" ).hover(
            function() {
                $( this ).find('.hide').fadeIn("slow"); ;
            }, function() {
                $( this ).find('.hide').fadeOut("slow"); 
            }

        );
        <div class="fourth"> 
            <div class="products">
                <h4 class="hide"><a href="#">Laern More</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the .stop() function to stop the previously started animations :

```
$( ".fourth" ).hover(

    function() {
        $( this ).find('.hide').stop().fadeIn("slow"); ;
    }, function() {
        $( this ).find('.hide').stop().fadeOut("slow"); 
    }

);
```

See the [jQuery .stop() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.stop()` to stop the currently-running animation and `.fadeToggle()` to keep the code simple.

```
$(".fourth").hover(function() {

   $(this).find('.hide').stop().fadeToggle("slow");

});
```

The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/z3Lrw/).